# Oracle BI Publisher format-number

Tags: oracle, numbers, format, rtf

I am currently realizing a treatment in Oracle EBS R12 (DBA 11g). And I stuck  at the level of the rtf,  more exactly I intend to format amounts with separators.
My problem is that the format in RTF works on round figures but not when those figures possess decimals as you can see in screen shots attached.

Can you please help me so i can work out this treatment ?

Thank You,
Best Regards

[image: Format-number not working on decimal numbers]

[image: Format-number from Oracle Mask "999G999D99"]

Answer (score 0):

If you sending output to PDF or rtf, it should work.

Since you are sending the output to Excel, Excel will treat that as a number, and auto format it, not knowing you want to keep the 0s. So your problem is more with Excel.

Here are some options

- If that is a currency, format as currency instead
- Try concatenating a space before or after text. Although that will effect what you can do with the cell in excel (like calculating from that cell).

Ideally, a bug should be opened with oracle, and the number formatting should be carried over to the Excel cell properties and it's decimal precision. Oracle will probably treat that as an enhancement though.